# To know a class by entering an array value

Tags: java

I have got one string array each in 2 different classes in java.

When I enter a value from any of the arrays, I want to get the class to which that array value belongs.

So how do I get to know the class just by entering an array value?

eg:

```
import java.io.*;
class Car {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The parts of a car are as follows");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + str[i]);
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            System.out.println(j + ch[j]);
        }
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose and enter any part name to group it under following                       categories:" + "\n" + "Engine" + "\t" + "\t" + "Bonet");
        String part = dis.readLine();
        if (part == ch[]) {
            System.out.println("Your choosen part is " + part + " and it comes under Engine category");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your choosen part is " + part + " and it comes under Bonet category");
        }
    }
}

class Engine {
    String ch[] = {"asd", "fgh"};
}

class Bonet {
    String str[] = {"qwe", "rty"};
}
```

now when a user enters asd i want to display to which class it belongs

Comment: Can you rephrase that as something that makes sense?

Comment: I am not sure how to understand your question. Could you add some examples with input and expected output?

Comment: People don't vote to close this question yet. OP is new to SO, give him a chance, wait with votes lets say 10 min from last update/edit.

Comment: @Pshemo, inclined to agree, although closing is far from final

Comment: Show us some code :).

Comment: @user2513831 don't get discouraged with closed question, it always can be reopen if you update your question fast and add some more details.

Comment: Are the arrays static? That would make sense, because they seem to be intended to be a property of the class, not an individual instance.

Comment: @user2513831 And where possible format it to include line breaks and indentation (as BackSlash has edited your current code to have)

Comment: As the question stands it might be vaguely answerable now

Comment: see here is the code and i hope now you know exactly what i am trying to ask. i am getting errors in this code.

Comment: I know we're all trying to be super-nice here and all but ... there's a limit to what SO is for. Teaching someone to program isn't one of them. The OP *really* needs to buy a good beginner's book on Java and start on Page 1 (or similarly start at the beginning of the Oracle tutorials). This would be the best possible answer. The code demonstrates the OP doesn't understand even the basics.

Comment: @Brian Roach Thank you so much for your answer but you see I am really trying to learn and its new for me. If you cannot help all I can say is thanks.

Comment: The biggest point I can make to help you (although it doesn't directly answer your question) is that fields ch and str belong to Engine and Bonet. That means that an Engine and Bonet must exist, but you never initialise one. You are using ch and str as if they belong to car, which they don't.

Comment: @user2513831 I would suggest you don't put bonnet and engine in the same file (for your own learning, not because its invalid code), this will make it clear that ch and str have nothing to do with the car class. An instance of a car may contain an instance of bonnet and engine (although it doesn't as its coded) but ch and str belong only to their respective classes

Comment: @Richard Tingle So to use ch and str in class Car what should I do?

Comment: See my answer, you ask an instance of engine or bonet to provide them to you

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels And the system works, I was always dubious how many questions really do come back from closure but this one has improved massively and can now be answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bare minimum changes to get this to work are as below. Key points:

- the contents of Engine and bonet **belong to instances of those classes** not to car
- arrays of size 5 have indicies 0,1,2,3,4, not 1,2,3,4,5
- Where going through an array in a loop **do not hard code the array size**, use `.length` instead

  ```
  import java.io.*;
  public class Car {

      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
          System.out.println("The parts of a car are as follows");

          Engine engine=new Engine(); //we must create any components we have
          Bonet bonet=new Bonet(); //we must create any components we have

          for (int i = 0; i <bonet.str.length; i++) { 
              System.out.println(i +":"+ bonet.str[i]);
          }
          for (int j = 0; j < engine.ch.length; j++) {
              System.out.println(j +":"+ engine.ch[j]);
          }
          DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
          System.out.println("Choose and enter any part name to group it under following                       categories:" + "\n" + "Engine" + "\t" + "\t" + "Bonet");
          String part = dis.readLine();

          boolean isInEngine=false; //assume isn't in engine, try to prove otherwise

          for(int i=0;i<engine.ch.length;i++){
              if (engine.ch[i].equals(part)){
                  isInEngine=true;
              }
          }

          if (isInEngine==true) {
              System.out.println("Your choosen part is " + part + " and it comes under Engine category");
          } else {
              System.out.println("Your choosen part is " + part + " and it comes under Bonet category");
          }
      }
  }

  class Engine {
      String ch[] = {"asd", "fgh"};
  }

  class Bonet {
      String str[] = {"qwe", "rty"};
  }
  ```

**Note; this is far from an optimal solution, ideas to consider:**

- It is bad practice to refer to the insides of annother class like this, it would be better for each class (engine and bonnet) to include a method `.testPart(String string)` that would return a boolean as to if it contains the part
- The code assumes that if its not in engine it must be in bonet, what if the user enters something crazy
- An array list (rather than an array) would allow us to use .contains(String string) rather than using a loop to look though the array
- The `DataInputStream` is no longer supported (note that it appears with a strike through in most IDEs), consider using `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` and then use `scanner.nextLine();` to get the line
- What if you add a third type of component, better to hold all your parts in an array, then you can easily add annother. An interface (or abstract base class) would promise that all the array contents held the `.testPart(String string)` and a `getName()` method; the array/arraylist would be declared as containing the interface/abstract-base-class
- You never actually create an instance of Car, which you would do by `Car car=new Car();`, the Car class could then have methods like `car.printOptions();` and `car.testComponent(String testString);`. The way you're doing it (one long main function) will work fine for small programs, but the bigger your program becomes the harder it will be to work like this. In this case the engine and bonet would be fields of the car class (which logically makes a lot more sense than them just 'hanging around')

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. I appreciate how you take beginners like me to understand things.

Comment: @user2513831 Awesome, please note though that the code i've posted is **not good**, just the bare minimum to get to started. I strongly suggest you look carefully at my Notes section

Comment: I will keep in my mind the note you made at the end. It will be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wont give you full code because I believe that creating it yourself will be better for you. Instead here are few facts that you need to take into consideration:

1. To have access to array stored in other class you would aether have to create instance of that class

   ```
   Engine engine = new Engine();
   engine.ch[0];
   ```

   or in your case you should probably make your array `static`

   ```
   class Engine {
       static String ch[] = { "asd", "fgh" };
   }
   ```

   and access it via class name `Engine.ch[0]`
2. Arrays are indexed from `0` to `arraySize-1`
3. To get size of array you can use its filed `length` and later use it like

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<Bonet.str.length; i++){
       System.out.println(i+Bonet.str[i]);
   }
   ```
4. `readLine()` from `DataInputStream` is depracated. Instead you can use `nextLine` from `java.util.Scanner`

   ```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   //...
   String part = scanner.nextLine();
   ```
5. To check if some object is stored in array you will have to iterate over all elements of that array and compare them with your object. Also remember that to compare String objects you should use `equals` method like `part.equals(otherString)`.

   But to make it with less code you can wrap your array into `List` and use its `contains(Object o)` method. To wrap array into list you can use `asList` method from `java.util.Arrays` class.

   ```
   if(Arrays.asList(Engine.ch).contains(part)){...
   ```

Comment: Thank you I will keep your points in mind while proceeding further. This is a useful piece of information and it will help me in correcting my mistakes and understanding my mistakes too. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2513831: This is the better answer of the two. 1+